# Is there any limit to the number of skills you can learn with the inherit skill feature?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

Since the latest patch of the game, you are now able to use the Inherit Skill feature, which allows you to make one of your character inherit up to 3 skills from another character, at the cost of losing this unit.

Can a single character inherit as many skills as he wants, or is there a number limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of skills a character can inherit from other characters, as long your character is compatible with those skills (a mage won't learn a sword skill) and in the limit of three skills per sacrified character. So you can inherit as many skills as you want without fearing that you could have created a better character with other sacrifices.

It is confirmed on the [Fire Emblem Heroes' wiki](https://feheroes.wiki/Inheritance_Guide):

> **There is no limit to how many skills a Hero can inherit overall.** However, each sacrificed Hero can only provide up to 3 inheritable skills.

Comment: Note that while a single character can inherit as many skills as you want, any one character can still only have one of each type of skill (weapon, support, special, A, B, and C) equipped at a time.